# Co-meager contains a perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

Let $A\subset\mathbb R$ be a meager set and $I\subset\mathbb R$ be an open interval.  So, $I\setminus A$ is co-meager in I.  I know, $I\setminus A$ has ccardinality $\mathfrak c$ and dense in $I.$   I did not see why $I\setminus A$ contains  a perfect set. I might miss some improtant proteries for co-meager set. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Do you know that every co-meager set contains a $G_{\delta}$ co-meager set (straightforward from the fact that every nowhere dense set is contained in a closed nowhere dense set) and every uncountable $G_{\delta}$ set contains a perfect set (can be proved with a bit of work, but don't need to resort to proving all uncountable Borel sets contain a perfect set)? There might be a more straightforward approach, however. Incidentally, your hesitation is good, as there exist $c$-dense sets that do not contain a perfect set.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, I know it I might miss it. In general, every uncountable Borel set contains a perfect set.  Thank you for your answer